# How can I deny all but one directory name with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file where I prevent users from physically accessing files from the browser (where they should only be loaded through the system)

```
Options -Indexes
Order deny,allow
deny from all
```

I have one problem though, sometimes I load files via AJAX and there I get 403 Forbidden. I have little experience with apache's mod_access. I've been reading up on the [directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory) since all my AJAX based files are in one directory called ajax.

But the thing is I need to deny access to all directories except ones called ajax and my regex skills are lacking.

An example directory structure is like this.

```
plugins/inventory/ajax
plugins/inventory/controller
plugins/inventory/view

plugins/packages/ajax
plugins/packages/controller
plugins/packages/view
```

The .htaccess file sits in the plugins directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That you need to do this in the first place is kind of a failure of project architecture.  Script files that shouldn't ever be accessible to the Web shouldn't be inside your DocumentRoot in the first place.

That said, this will probably work:

```
RewriteEngine on
<DirectoryMatch "/(?!.*/ajax$)">
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that, the reason for this is that people are writing plugins that are automatically loaded into the system and should be able to drop into a location.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  So, what, they need to be inside the DocumentRoot because they're publishing via HTTP PUT or something?

Comment: I get your point and it could be possible we could implement the plugins in a different way. They are just directories within the system developers can use to program addons for the system.

Comment: Seems like I get a 500 Internal Server Error with anything I try. Both <Directory> and <DirectoryMatch> and multiple combination of items from the documentation and your answer.

Comment: Check your server/vhost error log to see what the actual error is.  Possibly you don't have mod_rewrite loaded so the RewriteEngine directive is breaking?

Comment: @Ólafur: Both those directives aren't allowed inside the `.htaccess`, only in the server config. See their "Context" property in the manual page you linked to yourself.