# .htaccess: allow access to directories that begin with the letter "r" using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http

I have a .htaccess file where I want to deny access from all DIR's except the folders in `/docs/` that are called `r20` or `r21`, and I will want to add more DIR's in the future where they will start with r. What regex expression can I use? Thanks.

```html
RewriteEngine On

<DirectoryMatch "^/docs/r">
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: You can’t use `DirectoryMatch` in .htaccess in the first place, the context of that directive is `server config, virtual host`.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that, got it from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057744/how-can-i-deny-all-but-one-directory-name-with-htaccess

The other option I looked at was

`Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch "^/docs/r">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>`
But I wasn't sure if this was better or not.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use _paths_ with `FilesMatch`, the documentation explicitly uses the term “filename”. You could probably also do it with a combination of a RewriteCond and a RewriteRule, the condition would check that the request URI was _not_ starting with `/docs/r`, and the rule would match all paths starting with `docs/`, and simply apply the `F` flag for Forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe's suggestion, this works for me.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/docs/r
RewriteRule !^/docs - [F]
```